# Keyboard shortcuts for "Straighten" in iPhoto?

Tags: keyboard, photos.app

If you've used iPhoto for photo retouching, you probably know the Straighten functionality.

[image]

My question is, **are there any keyboard shortcuts for rotating the photo, or is mouse & the slider the only way**? Any other useful tips regarding this are of course also welcome.

It can be somewhat slow and awkward to do this with mouse/trackpad for each photo (especially if your mouse is not the most accurate one, like my Logitech bluetooth mouse). In iPhoto '09 they made matters worse by removing the small buttons next to the slider that you could click to rotate by one step (0.1 degrees).

Comment: And in iPhoto '11 you can only straighten in **0.6°** steps. Which makes it pretty much unacceptable even for casual photo retouching. :(

Answer (score 1):

You can press the S key to activate the straighten tool. And the return key will save any changes. Unfortunately, I am not sure how to control the slider in order to actually make a change using the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a trackpad you can use two-finger-rotation gestures in Straighten mode. See http://www.cnet.com/news/quick-tip-iphoto-11-trackpad-gestures/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Accessibility Inspector](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Accessibility/Conceptual/AccessibilityMacOSX/OSXAXTesting/OSXAXTestingApps.html) to input arbitrary numbers for the amount of rotation. See this post [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/53237/14994) for usage instructions.
Remember to press `Set value` to change the number and input numbers with decimal point, e.g. 4.0.

[image: Set value in Accessibility Inspector to rotate picture in iPhoto]

[image: zoomed in view of Accessibility Inspector for iPhoto]